# When did Samuel Friedrich Walcker die?

Tags: 19th-century, germany, death-records, russia

I've been searching for this piece of information for quite a while, but so far, it has been fruitless. I've searched through familysearch.org at least half a dozen times. Here's what I have on him so far:

- b. **7 Oct 1770** | [Birth Certificate](https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/N5N2-2MV)
- He lived in Steinheim an der Murr, Neckar, Württemberg, Germany
- He was a butcher
- He emigrated with his family to **[Neu Freudental](http://www.grhs.org/vr/vhistory/neu_freudental.htm), Russia** in 1817 due to famine. However, Neu Freudental was not founded until 1828, which does not make sense. My geuss is that he stayed somewhere else in Russia for those eleven years.
- Father: **Johann Ludwig Walcker** b. **4 Aug 1744** d. **10 Nov 1793**
- Mother: **Eva Agnes Zucker** chr. **30 Nov 1744** d. **13 Feb 1819** |
- Married **Anna Maria Christiana Pfleiderer** on **21 Sep 1803** | [Marriage Certificate](https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/NZ2Y-1VZ)
- Anna Maria Christiana Pfleiderer b. **25 Sep 1782** d. *unknown* | [Marriage Certificate](https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/NZ2Y-1VZ) | [Birth Certificate](https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/NN8V-2F4)
- Anna Maria Christiana Pfleiderer often went by the name **Christiana Pfleiderer**
- Samuel Friedrich Walcker often went by **Friedrich Walcker** | ex. [Son's birth Certificate](https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/NL3F-WC7)
- "Friedrich" was spelled "Fridrich" on at least three occasions | [Sons' birth Certificates 1](https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/NCWN-7SW) [2](https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/NCWN-QHS) [3](https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/NL3F-W7Z)
- "Friedrich was also spelled "Friederick" sometimes.
- Samuel and Anna had at least eight children:

  1. **Johann Friedrich Walcker** b. **24 May 1803** d. *unknown* | [Birth Certificate](https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/NL3F-WC7)
  2. **Ludwig Friedrich Walcker** b. **11 May 1805** d. **12 May 1806** | [Birth, Death Cert.](https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/NCWN-SLP)
  3. **Sibilla Christiana Walcker** b. **22 Mar 1807** d. *unknown* | [Birth Certificate](https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/N5N2-K9F)
  4. Unnamed child, unknown gender (twin) b. **22 Mar 1807** | *Unfortunately, I've lost my source for this child.*
  5. **Johann Ludwig Walcker** (he often went by Ludwig Walcker) b. **25 Aug 1809** d. **27 Sep 1870** | [Birth Certificate](https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/NCWN-7SW)
  6. **Eberhardt Johann Walcker** b. **11 Sep 1811** d. **1 Sep 1812** | [Birth, Death Cert.](https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/NCWN-QHS)
  7. **Catharina Rosina Walcker** b. **14 June 1813** d. **19 Nov 1813** | [Birth, Death Cert.](https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/NL3F-W7Z)
  8. **Philipp Heinrich Walcker** b. **23 Oct 1814** d. *unknown* | [Birth Certificate](https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/NCWN-QY7)

So, that's what I've found so far. Right now, I'm trying to find out when Samuel Friedrich Walcker died.

Comment: If he died in Russia, your odds of finding records are much lower than if he died in Germany.

Answer (score 2):

You might try searching the ["Germans from Russia"](http://www.grhs.org/) site (registration required) as it does seem to mention both [Neu Freudental](http://www.grhs.org/search/search.php?media_only=0&query=neu+freudental&search=1&type=phrase&mark=mark+yellow&results=10&db=0&prefix=search1_) and [Walcker](http://www.grhs.org/search/search.php?media_only=0&query=Walcker&search=1&type=phrase&mark=mark+yellow&results=10&db=0&prefix=search1_).

Comment: Good find, but unfortunately, my budget right now doesn't allot much to genealogy. :(

Comment: Luke, you might try posting this question on their facebook page. Perhaps some kind soul who is a member will do a look up for you. It can't hurt! :)